# log4j version 2 - no debug output

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I cannot get log4j version 2 running, so I am trying to see its own debug messages. This doesn't debug anything to the console:

```
java -Dlog4j.debug -jar project-with-dependencies.jar
```

Which switch shall we use?

**If it matters:**

I am using netbeans + maven, with dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta8</version>
</dependency>
```

and I use this inside the class:

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(App.class.getName());
```

**Edit:**

Looks like the switch `-Dlog4j.debug` is missing in the new version. Then how can I see which XML configuration file is it loading? Apparently it ignores my XML file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this kind of log4j2 debugging doesn't exist anymore. see [jira: LOG4J2-282](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-282)